# What is Google Meet's "Google Drive storage" feature?

Tags: google-drive, google-meet

https://apps.google.com/intl/en/meet/pricing/ states **only** G Suite Enterprise users get the "Meeting recording saved to Google Drive" feature. Yet it also states everybody, including free users, get "Google Drive storage".

How does that make sense? Since Google Meet doesn't support uploading files to chat, what is this Storage feature used for if it **doesn't** record meetings (for most users)?

[image: Google Drive in Google Meet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is this Storage feature used for if it doesn't record meetings (for most users)?

When you create an account via Gmail by default you get  15 GB free storage on Google Drive. That is the storage mentioned on the pricing page.
Meeting recordings are saved on Google Drive only for those who have G-Suite Enterprise as the feature is on available to them as stated [here](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9308681):

> This feature is available with the G Suite Enterprise and G Suite Enterprise for Education editions.

> How does that make sense?

If you have a normal account you don't have the recording feature, so you can't save meeting recordings to Google Drive. If you have a G-Suite account, the recording feature is available to you, and when your recordings are automatically save to Google Drive.

Comment: So basically, everything under **COLLABORATION FEATURES** is more about Google Drive than Google Meet. Not sure why it means people should take away points from this question.